# Using # in landing page url

Tags: search, anchor, google-ads-api, hashtag

I'm using `mysite.com/#contact` as a landing page URL in some of the PPC campaigns, but when Google or Bing ads their URL parameters, I get url like `mysite.com/#contact?campaign=x&source=x..` and the browser doesn't scroll down to the `#contact anchor`.

Any way to fix this? Or do I need to use a different URL?

Answer (score 0):

In order to scroll down to the anchor it has to be at the very end of your url **mysite.com?campaighn=x&source=x[...]#contact**

I never used PPC ads so I don't know how to fix it, but at least that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to detect the URL parameter and use JavaScript to scroll to the specific location if true.

Untested combination of PHP / JS:

```
<?php if ( isset( $_GET['campaign'] ) { ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     //JS stuff
     </script>
<?php } ?>
```